# ExtJS prevent resizecolumn event while loading columns

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm working on an ExtJS 6.2 project. I need to perform some operations when the columns in a grid a resized. I think the correct event to do so is *columnresize*. The problem is, since the columns are being loaded from a database dynamically, this event is fired every time a new column is added to the grid, and I would like to prevent it. I mean, I need this event to be fired only when every column is loaded.

I've tried to set a flag  (named *lFirstInit*) that would be *false* once the columns are loaded form database, but the *columnresize* event keeps on being fired from the start.

How could I approach this, please? Thanks.

**View:**

```
Ext.define('App.view.TMainBrowseGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.TMainBrowseGrid',

    requires: [
        'App.view.TMainBrowseGridViewModel',
        'App.view.override.TMainBrowseGrid',
        'Ext.view.Table',
        'Ext.grid.column.RowNumberer',
        'App.view.TMainBrowseGridViewController'
    ],

    controller: 'TMainBrowseGrid',

    config: {
        oParent: null,
        cBrwName: '',
        cCodForm: ''
    },

    viewModel: {
        type: 'TMainBrowseGrid'
    },

    flex: 1,

    columns: [
        {
            xtype: 'rownumberer',
            itemId: 'oColRowNum'
        }
    ],

    listeners: {
        columnresize: 'onGridpanelColumnResize',
    }

});
```

**Controller**

```
Ext.define('App.view.TMainBrowseGridViewController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.TMainBrowseGrid',

    onGridpanelColumnResize: function (component, column, width, eOpts) {
        // THINGS TO DO...
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have count how many columns would be rendered on UI ? If yes then you can compare rendered columns count with actual column count. If you can demonstrate some dummy code I can code it.

Comment: Could you add the `columnresize` listener programatically in the `refresh` listener of the grid view?

Answer (score 1):

We have finally discarded the 'columnresize' approach. We thought it is more reliable performing thos operations when clicking on a 'Close' button. However, I would like to thank you for your suggestions, especially the person who posted the answer below, and later removed it before I could mark it as the chosen answer. This was the code he/she posted:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [{
        name: 'Lisa',
        email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-111-1224'
    }, {
        name: 'Bart',
        email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1234'
    }, {
        name: 'Homer',
        email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1244'
    }, {
        name: 'Marge',
        email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1254'
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name'
    }, {
        text: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
    }],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        columnresize: function(ct, column, width, eOpts){
            if(ct.containsFocus){// It will true when we resize column.
                alert('resize');
                console.log(`${column.text} Column resized`);
            }
        }
    }
});
```